# gitlab runner unable to clone repository after update to version 8.12

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci-runner

After updating GitLab community edition to 8.12.2 the CI runner is no longer able to perform a git clone.

We receive the following error in the build output:

```
Running with gitlab-ci-multi-runner 1.6.0 (01b3ea1)
Using Shell executor...
Running on ip-xxx-xx-xx-xxx...
Cloning repository...
Cloning into '/home/ubuntu/builds/fe761fb8/0/FuseOS/xxxxx'...
fatal: unable to access 'https://gitlab-ci-token:xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx@git.xxxx.xxx/example/repo.git/': The requested URL returned error: 403
ERROR: Build failed: exit status 1
```

We have also tried triggering the build by an admin user with no luck. We are aware of the new authentication introduced in Gitlab 8.12, but we haven't seen any changes that need to be updated. The runner has also been re-registered but that didn't resolve the issue.

Are there any new settings that need to be updated?